# How do i pick a random number to use in a array

Tags: python

I have no clue what is wrong sorry if it's simple I'm learning python

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Scripts\magic8.py", line 12, in <module>
    thinker()
  File "Scripts\magic8.py", line 8, in thinker
    toprint = responses[number]
TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable
```

and my code:

```
from time import sleep
import random
responses = {'Probably', 'Probably not', 'Yes', 'No', 'Dont count on it', 'Cant tell you now!'}
def thinker ():
    number = random.randint(0, 5)
    number = int(number)
    print(number)
    toprint = responses[number]
    print(toprint)
while True:
    input("Ask the almighty magic 8 ball your question: ")
    thinker()
```

Comment: As in the other answers, using a list is the better option, but if you must use a set, you can use `set.pop()` to get random elements of the set, at the same time, removing those elements.

Comment: `set.pop()` removes an *arbitrary* element, but the choice is not *random* in a particularly useful sense - it depends on the internal implementation details of the set data structure, but not on any deliberate attempt to create randomness.

Answer (score 1):

This is your issue.You cannot index out elements of a set.
You are using responses as a set because you have used `{}`
Instead use `[]`
What you can do is use a list instead.

```
responses = ['Probably', 'Probably not', 'Yes', 'No', 'Dont count on it', 'Cant tell you now!']
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do:

```
responses = ['Probably', 'Probably not', 'Yes', 'No', 'Dont count on it', 'Cant tell you now!']
```

instead of:

```
responses = {'Probably', 'Probably not', 'Yes', 'No', 'Dont count on it', 'Cant tell you now!'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a list

```py
responses = ['Probably', 'Probably not', 'Yes', 'No', 'Dont count on it', 'Cant tell you now!']
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a set. You need a list.

```
responses = ['Probably', 'Probably not', 'Yes', 'No',....]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want `responses` to be a list rather than a set.  To do this, use brackets instead of braces:

```
responses = ['Probably', 'Probably not', 'Yes', 'No', 'Dont count on it', 'Cant tell you now!']
```

Also, the `number = int(number)` line is redundant since `random.randint` returns an integer.